# Blender wireframe material missing some edges

Tags: shaders, graph-editor, wireframe

I am trying to create a material to draw a mesh in wireframe mode. Thhe result will the be applied on top of another render, so I want the edges to be painted as black and the rest of the surface to be transparent.

I have tried to create this material, but I'm missing some edges as shown in the images.

Mesh:
[image]

Material and render view:
[image]

I have also tried with R channel for the parametric. That renders other edges, but still not all when combining both modes.

How should I configure the material to produce the desired output?

Comment: Hello :). Just to be clear - do you want to render ALL of the edges? Because it seems you're avoiding the border around your plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your mesh is altready triangulated, you can use the *Wireframe Node*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to set the wireframe parameter to 1, in the viewport overlay options.

[image: Set wireframe to 1.000]

Answer (score 0):

The *Parametric* output returns the U and V of the [Barycentric Coordinates](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/barycentric-coordinates) of the shading point in the mesh, triangulated for rendering. For some reason, it doesn't give you W for free, but it can be derived from the other two: `W=1-(U+V)`.

U=0 (your R channel) gives one side of the triangle. V=0 and W=0 the other two.

So you could use something like this to pick out all the edges:

[image]

but as you can see, distances are UVW normalized lengths.. without knowing the dimensions of the containing triangle, I don't think you can get absolute, rather than relative, thicknesses for the lines.

Comment: .. so it's better to use the Wireframe node as @Jachym has answered.